# MySQL Inserting an entry where number of values < number of columns

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

I have a python script executing SQL commands and am trying to insert all my data into a table. The problem is I have a list of entries, say:

```
"Bob", "bob@gmail.com"
"John", "john@gmail.com", "(123)-456-7890"
"Tom", "tom@gmail.com", "(123)-456-7890"
```

So the first entry will not have the last value that the other two entries have. How can I insert into my table with one command? Right now I loop through the entries and attempt to insert them but receive `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`.

I have tried both `INSERT INTO myTable (FirstName, email, phone) VALUES(...)` as well as `INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(...)` omitting the table columns.

Comment: Put only the columns you're gonna populate.
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, email) VALUES ("Tom", "tom@hello.it")

Answer (score 0):

Can the Python script just insert a NULL value when the value isn't available?  So:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (FirstName, email, phone) VALUES("Bob", "bob@gmail.com", NULL)
```

Comment: It is easy in this case to do it because I can just check the length and if it's less than 1 of the columns length I can append a NULL. But what if it was somewhere in the middle? Or if there were multiple

Comment: If each value is stored in a variable, you'd just replace missing values with NULL.  If you have a string in a single variable, it would require some parsing.  It really depends on how the Python script is written and how much control you have over it.

Comment: Yeah i just realized I've already replaced all empty values with NULL just for some reason the last value in the list does not show up as "" it's literally just empty so doesn't get replaced with anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are assuming the phone will be included most of the time, you can pass 'NULL' when the phone number is not provided and use the verbose

```
INSERT INTO myTable (FirstName, email, phone) VALUES('John', 'js@js.com', NULL)
```

I would suggest writing a rudimentary ORM that will take whatever you give it and adjust the INSERT statement as needed.  i.e. If your object doesn't have the phone number property populated, it can generate the insert statement as such:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (FirstName, email) VALUES('John', 'js@js.com')
```

Then if the phone number is populated, it will build the insert statement with the phone number column included.